# How to loop through all the characters in a string?

Tags: php

I tried doing it like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($s); $i++) {
    $char = $s[$i]; 
    ...
}
```

but it appears to be wrong when characters that don't fit into 1 byte are involved. strlen("ää") returns 4 for example which would suggest they are composed of 2 bytes.

How do I go through each character in php?

Answer (score 5):

That code loops through the **bytes** in the string, not the **characters**.... use the [mb_*](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) functions for working with multibyte character strings

```
for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($s); $i++) {
    $char = mb_substr($s, $i, 1);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple one-line "trick" to get set of multibyte characters using `preg_split` function with `/u` (utf-8) modifier:

```
$str = "äänä";
$chars = preg_split("//u", $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($chars);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ä
    [1] => ä
    [2] => n
    [3] => ä
)
```